# How can I test an ICMP Re-direct message?

Tags: routing, route, icmp

I want to test whether my linux machine is actually accepting ICMP re-direct message and updating the entry in routing table.This is what i have done so far to achieve the same.

1. Simulated a ICMP redirect message with 0,1,2,3 code from ostinato packet generator and forwarded it to Linux machine.

still the routing table is not getting updated with the new gateway.

The below shown is the current routing table in my machine.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.222.4.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

All I want to test is whether the host machine is updating the routing table after receiving ICMP redirect message.